# FireFox Selenium Webdriver does not load Jquery from Google Api

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver api to drive firefox. The problem is that the jquery files located at the Google api web site are not loading. Which caused an error.

What should I do so that the files located on

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js
```

should load?

The website loads the javascript in the head tag. It shows an error in the console that 
    jQuery is not defined.

However I have noticed now that if you refresh it for couple of times the file loads. What should i do to fix it now?

code used to load the page

```
@browser = $browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
@browser.navigate.to("http://www.example.com")
@browser.find_element(:link_text, "social").click
```

Using ruby.

Comment: Is the selenium webdriver throwing any error?

Comment: Are you saying that while executing tests, Firefox doesn't load jQuery, effectively making the pages you're testing unusable? Or are you trying to load jQuery programatically for tests and use it there? Is there any runtime error, or at least JS error in the JS console?

Comment: @HemChe  Question has been updated!

Comment: @Slanec : Question updated!

Comment: Does the issue exists even if you open the page manually?

Comment: No the issue does not exist when I use it manually.. I mean to say in a normal Firefox instance.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to reproduce it locally. Does this happen with every page that loads jQuery from Google? Try, let's say, Stack Overflow, or any other similar page that uses jQuery heavily.

Comment: @Slanec: Its weird, i tested your way and stackoverflow works fine.Any suggestions?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. WebDriver should not interfere with it in any way. The loading part is absolutely in the hands of FF. Try creating a new profile and try it manually, again. Or try creating a new profile for the testing script if you're reusing the same one again and again.

Comment: @Slanec do me a last favor, i have added the code i am using, please check if it is fine.. ruby is the language..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference the solution is being posted. The problem was that the Firefox profile was looking for cached files. to disable caching use the following code.

```
FirefoxProfile ff = new FirefoxProfile();
ff.setPreference("browser.cache.disk.enable", false);
```

in ruby code goes like this

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.cache.disk.enable'] = false

@driver = $browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
```